# How to use splitview's pane in visualstate to achieve adaptive effect in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, uwp-xaml

I have a few navigation buttons inside StackPanel, I want to put them inside the splitview's pane. When the splitview's pane is open, the stackpanel's orientation is horizontal, and when the pane is closed the stackpanel's orientation is vertical so that user would always be able to see the navigation buttons.
The XAML code is as follows

```
             <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PaneViewStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="PaneClosedState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <StateTrigger  IsActive="{Binding Path=IsPaneOpen, ElementName=SplitView, Converter={StaticResource BooleanNegationConverter}}"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="NavigationControl.RootGrid.StackPanel.Orientation" Value="Vertical"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="PaneOpenState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <StateTrigger IsActive="{Binding Path=IsPaneOpen, ElementName=SplitView}"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="NavigationControl.RootGrid.StackPanel.Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
```

But I got the error like The attachable property `'IsPaneOpen' was not found in type 'SplitView'.`
I got plane B, that is to use events like `OnPaneClosing` and `OnPaneOpen`, however there is only `PaneClosing` event, no openning event. I'm wondering if anyone can give any suggestion.

Comment: I think you're suppose to use StateTrigger here and not AdaptiveTrigger, something like <StateTrigger IsActive="{Binding Path=IsPaneOpen, ElementName=SplitView}" />

Comment: @AndreyAshikhmin  Still it will not trigger the event, no matter whether the pane is open or closed.  I also tested with the visibility of some other controls to ensure it is not NavigationControl.RootGrid.StackPanel.Orientation's problem

Comment: Try to name your StackPanel, f.e. 'AdaptiveStackPanel' and set target as this: `AdaptiveStackPanel.Orientation`

Answer (score 1):

Adaptive triggers use `MinWidth` and `MinHeight` to check for trigger conditions. It doesn't check for any Boolean conditions. You need to use `StateTrigger` and bind `IsPaneOpen` to `IsActive` to trigger the "PaneOpenState". But if you want to trigger the "PaneClosedState", you cannot directly bind it to `IsActive` of the `StateTrigger`. You need to have some other State Triggers that are derived from StateTriggerBase Class, like these awesome [WindowsStateTriggers](https://github.com/dotMorten/WindowsStateTriggers). I am using `IsFalseStateTrigger` from the above said collection.

The code should be like:

```
<Page ...
    xmlns:triggers="using:WindowsStateTriggers">
...

<VisualState x:Name="PaneOpenState">
    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
        <StateTrigger IsActive="{Binding IsPaneOpen, ElementName=MySplit}"/>
    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
    <VisualState.Setters>
        <Setter Target="NavigationControl.RootGrid.StackPanel.Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
    </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
<VisualState x:Name="PaneClosedState">
    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
        <triggers:IsFalseStateTrigger Value="{Binding ElementName=MySplit, Path=IsPaneOpen}" />
    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
    <VisualState.Setters>
        <Setter Target="NavigationControl.RootGrid.StackPanel.Orientation" Value="Vertical"/>
    </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
```

**Edit**

After one of our friends pointed out, I came to know that I forgot the most obvious way to do this instead of using `IsFalseStateTrigger`. You can use a converter like `NotTrueConverter` that negates the Boolean and use it in the "PaneClosedState" using the `StateTrigger`

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to simply use some kind of NegBoolean converter for PaneClosedState and then bind them?

Comment: @AndreyAshikhmin I'm sorry I forgot the most obvious way to do that. I'll edit my answer. Thanks :)